# "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741792 Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cl.exe

I'm trying to build of my application using VS2017, but this is returning this message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5):
>   error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741792.

I tried several things, I discovered that this error code is equivalent to 0xc0000020, but I could not walk very much with the subject.

Has anyone ever experienced this? or do you know what 0xc0000020 means?

Thanks, I had installed on my VS2013 machine, I removed and installed the V2017.

Comment: Which version of the VS2017 do you have installed? also the ntstatus code is [`STATUS_INVALID_FILE_FOR_SECTION

{Bad File} The attributes of the specified mapping file for a section of memory cannot be read.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx). Does this happen during compilation or linking, do you try to link in custom resources?

Comment: It is nasty, run chkdsk.exe to verify disk drive health.

Comment: This happens when I try to compile any code, it can even be a new project created.

Comment: Examining the file listed on my computer shows that line is dealing with creating precompiled headers. I'd try turning them off completely and seeing if that works. If you must have them, verify you have only one file set to create the header and the rest set to use it or not as appropriate. The precompiled header must always be the first include in any file that creates or uses it. If the problem persists you may have a corrupt installation. I'd take a look at that file to see what yours says.

Comment: the pch may just be the first thing to get passed to the compiler. Have you tried a repair-install of VS2017 or manually calling cl.exe ?

Comment: I tried to uninstall and reinstall VS2017, but with no result, it follows the complete log of an application that I am trying to compile


https://pastebin.com/A6gQURWQ